# How to get salesforce instance url

Tags: apex, chatter

To access chatter rest api using APEX code, I need salesforce instance server url in following format:

`https://na17.salesforce.com`

Is there any method which works in all cases

Case 1: Any Development Org

Case 2: My Domain Enabled

Case 3: Sandbox

Case 4: Managed Package

Comment: Rather than making a callout to the Chatter REST API, you may want to consider calling the classes in the ConnectApi Apex namespace instead. They provide almost all the functionality that the REST API does. Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_overview.htm

Comment: I know, That's also my preference, but I was looking for endorsement details for a particular topic, which is not available via ConnectAPI Apex namespace.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You are looking for [`URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm).

**Edit**

The Winter 19 release is introducing another method to get the URL, which will give you the *canonical* URL for your org: [`URL.getOrgDomainUrl()`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm).

> Returns the canonical URL for your org. For example, `https://yourDomain.my.salesforce.com` or, for orgs without My Domain enabled, `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com`.

---

Both of the above methods return a `System.URL`. If you would like the string version, simply call `.toExternalForm()` on that instance. For example:

```
String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

Comment: System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm() to be more precise.

Comment: Any idea how to get your instance if you have mydomain enabled ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke You need to use the status/trust API. See https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/#!/instances/getInstanceAliasByKey

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Didn't see that you had pinged this answer until just now.

Comment: Any idea how to get the Base URL in visualforce pages so that I don't have to hardcode in VF pages.

Comment: `System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm().substringBefore('.visual').substringAfter('.')`

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Salesforce is now adding new method in Winter19 i.e. System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl()

Answer (score 21):

To retrieve a URL object containing the full beginning portion of the URL, such as "https://na17.salesforce.com", you may use the static method:

```
    System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL();  // Yields URL object for https://xxxx.salesforce.com
```

As Ashish notes above, suffixing this method with ".toExternalForm()" will convert the URL object into its text representation, as follows:

```
    System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();  // Yields string "https://xxxx.salesforce.com"
```

Furthermore, if you wish to retrieve only the subdomain portion of the URL (the "na17" part to the left of the ".salesforce.com" domain), use:

```
    System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().getHost();  // Yields subdomain (host) as string
```

These methods will work reliably across Production, Sandboxes, Dev Orgs, etc. Which one you choose depends upon your specific need in the code that you are writing.

Lastly, if you're trying to create a host-independent object link, you may do so as follows:

```
    String link = '<a href="' + System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + sObject.Id + '" target="_blank">sObject Link</a>';
```

Comment: Any idea how to get your instance if you have mydomain enabled ?

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach to get just the instance, as in managed packages the other one approaching is not working for me

```
String urlInstance = String.valueof(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL()).replace('Url:[delegate=','').replace(']','');
String[] instance = urlInstance.split('\\.');
req.setEndpoint('https://'+instance[1]+'.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/cloudmobile/myservice/');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the instance name from the Organization object using:

select InstanceName from Organization

Unlike the solutions using 'System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL()...' this will work for you in:

Case 1: Any Development Org
Case 2: My Domain Enabled
Case 3: Sandbox
Case 4: Managed Package

Comment: By virtue of its simplicity and elegance, yours is the most useful solution, and maybe the only one that can be accomplished quickly in a developer console. You need only enter the one-line SOQL query into the built-in Query Editor.

Answer (score 2):

The OLD way was to use getSalesforceBaseUrl()

That has been deprecated. From the docs:

In API version 59.0 and later, this method is deprecated and versioned out. Use getOrgDomainUrl() to get the canonical URL for your org or use getCurrentRequestUrl() to get the URL of an entire request on a Salesforce instance. Returns the URL of the current connection to the Salesforce org.

**getOrgDomainUrl()**

Returns the canonical URL for your org. For example, https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com.
(Use this for the forseeable future.)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_Url_getOrgDomainUrl

Answer (score 1):

DomainCreator class is now provided by Salesforce, we can use this class to get different urls.

Salesforce documentation link for reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_DomainCreator.htm