# how to get the url of the logged in user from the workbench

Tags: url

in my one of visualforcepages,i had hardcoded the url like below,
https://na34.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp
and url will be different for different users and i hardcoded prefix also,
in salesforce,now to dnt to hardcode them,i want to in salesforce,where the prefix and url of the org is stored,thanks in advance,

Comment: In my project,i had used like this             <apex:outputLink value="https://na15.salesforce.com/{!checkBoxRecord.objectRecord}"  target="_tab">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the method `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL();`  in your VF page controller.

[How to get salesforce instance url](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64616/how-to-get-salesforce-instance-url) might be helpful.

Comment: how i can get the prefix